# How to compute sum series 1+1/2...+1/n

Tags: java, recursion

I'm having trouble trying to find the sum of this series non-recursively 
So far I have:

```
public static double sum_nr(int n) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        result=result+1/(i+1);
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args){ 
    int n= 4;
    System.out.println("Calculation for sum_nr(n) " + n + " is "+ sum_nr(n));
}
```

I keep getting 0.0 as the sum.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's due to not using the right type. You're doing integer division rather than using a float type.

```
public static double sum_nr(int n) {
    double result = 0;
    for (double i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        result=result+1.0/(i+1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The `1.0` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Christian it is if you're not casting `i` as a double

Comment: Trying this way if n was equal to 4, the sum would be 2.08333 but when this code is implemented, the answer is 1.2833333. I think it's off by a little.

Comment: @user2985442 that's because you're skipping the first number in the sum , 1. You should either start i at 0, or add 1/i in each iteration.

Comment: When I tried starting i at 0, i got 2.283333 instead if 2.0833. It's very close but somewhere I think .200 is being add to the sum.

Comment: I've changed the answer to start the enumeration off at 0 and then also changed the less than or equal to operator to a less than operator. That resulted in the 0.2 added in. Running that code with the value of 4 passed in results in 2.08333 being returned.

Answer (score 0):

Integer division will lead to 0 results. you should use `float`/`double` instead of `int` for variable `result`.

Comment: I tried result=result+(1/(i+1)); adding the extra parenthesis around it, but i'm still getting 0.0 as the the sum. Also I changed int result=0; to double result=0.0.

Comment: @user2985442 The problem is related to integer division int i = 1/2 will be 0

Answer (score 0):

result=result+1/(i+1); will always give 0 as i is an integer. Assign i value to a float and use that

> float result = 0f; // declare result as float too or double  for (int
>   i = 1; i<=n; i++)
>       { float val = i;
>           result=result+1/(float+1);
>       }

Answer (score 0):

Same as everyone else says but their answers aren't complete.

```
public static double sum_nr(int n) {
    float result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i<=n; i++){
        result=result+1/((float)i+1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

`result` needs to be a float, or double, but you also need to cast `i` as a float, or double, as well. No need to create a new variable

Answer (score 0):

The series you are referring to is the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)). There's a closed form approximation for this.

```
H(n) = ln(n) + gamma + 1/(2n) - 1/(12n^2)
```

where gamma is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496116/is-there-a-partial-sum-formula-for-the-harmonic-series).

In Java, here's some code to both compute correctly and show the difference of the approximation to the actual as `n` grows. It will become asymptotically smaller:

```
constant double EULER_MASCHERONI = 0.57721566490153286060651209008240243104215933593992;

public static double approximateHarmonicSummation(int n) {
    return Math.log(n) + EULER_MASCHERONI + 0.5 * n - 1.0 / (12.0 * Math.pow(n, 2));
}

public static double sum_nr(int n) {
    double result = 0;
    for (double i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result += 1.0 / (i + 1);
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double approx = 0.0;
    double actual = 0.0;
    for (int n = 0; n < 1000; n++) {
       approx = approximateHarmonicSummation(n);
       actual = sum_nr(n);
       System.out.println("Calculation for approximation of sum_nr(n) " + n + " is "+ approx);
       System.out.println("Calculation of sum_nr(n) " + n + " is "+ actual);
       System.out.printlin("Difference = " + (actual - approx) + "\n");
    }
}
```

Hopefully that helps.